# Memory leaks in C# hosted Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, memory-leaks

i have a simple app, that's creating a Powershell runspace:

```
        var iis = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
        iis.ExecutionPolicy = ExecutionPolicy.Unrestricted;
        iis.LanguageMode = PSLanguageMode.FullLanguage;
        iis.ThreadOptions = PSThreadOptions.UseNewThread;
        iis.DisableFormatUpdates = true;

        m_Settings = new PSInvocationSettings
        {
            Host = new PSHostProxy(new PSUIStub()),
        };

        m_RunspacePool = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspacePool(iis);
        m_RunspacePool.CleanupInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
        m_RunspacePool.SetMaxRunspaces(1);
        m_RunspacePool.SetMinRunspaces(1);
        m_RunspacePool.Open();
```

And then uses it to execute several PowerShell scripts. Each RUN is invoked by external event (runs in another thread) and happens ussualy with 20-50 seconds after the foregoing RUN:

```
RUN:
{
  foreach(var scriptName in scripts)
  {
    var ps = PowerShell.Create();
    ps.RunspacePool = m_RunspacePool;
    var input = new PSDataCollection<string>();

    ps.AddCommand(Path.Combine(scriptPath, scriptName));
    ps.AddArgument(args);

    // Call
    ps.Invoke(input, m_Output, m_Settings);
    ...
    m_Output.Clear();
    input.Clear();
    input.Dispose();

    ps.Dispose();
    ps = null;
  }
}
```

And memory usage of this keeps raising during the run, although the scripts are always the same and even their results are the same. Each cycle creates a bunch (well like thousands of them, but i suppose the number is given by length of the executed scripts...) of SessionStateCmdLetEntry and those are never disposed and GCed, because of reference by a TimerCallback created by RunspacePoolInternal. This can take up to 1GB of memory per day...

Does anyone have tips, what else should I dispose or clear to avoid stashing the SessionStateCmdLetEntries? Or any workarounds for this?

I just need a long running process, that invokes several Powershell scripts and does not eat up memory.. I've also tried not reusing the RunSpacePool and creating a new Runspace for each RUN and even for each script, but it did not help at all...

Thanks for any help...

Comment: "... and those are never disposed and GCed, because of reference by a TimerCallback created by RunspacePoolInternal. This can take up to 1GB of memory per day". Nice digging, sounds like [an excellent bug report description](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues) :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That is only relevant for *PowerShell Core* unfortunately.  I'm assuming the OP is using a reference to the local *Windows PowerShell*.

Comment: Can you post [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the memory leak when you manage the runspaces manually (rather than using a runspace pool)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen the code is basically the same as the example before, only instead of RunspacePool, i've created Runspace. Used the same settings, same host, etc.. But I have investigated more on this and found out that the leak is not caused by the C# code itself, but by the powershell scripts I've run through it. One of the scripts i've used to test created its own RunspacePool and PowerShell instance and used it to run some code. And this specific action then ended up in a memory leak. Although I believe that the script is well written and should not cause a leak, it is not a C# problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows out, that the leak is not caused by the C# code, but by a PowerShell script run through this. The script creates its own RunspacePool and PowerShell instance to execute some specific code and this causes the memory leak.